# Image does not work on update method | Laravel + VueJs

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, axios, image-upload

I managed to create a post with image and now I want to be able to update it too. Everything was working fine with the update method until I added the option to update the image as well. Everything gets updated except the image which gives me a 500 Internal server error.

I can save the image when I create a post, but if I try to update a post image it gives me 500 internal server error.
When I inspect the console it looks like the following:

[image]

This is my update method in the controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $exploded = explode(',', request('image'));
    $decoded = base64_decode($exploded[1]);
    if(str_contains($exploded[0], 'jpeg'))
        $extension = 'jpg';
    else
        $extension = 'png';   

    $fileName = str_random().'.'.$extension;
    $path = public_path().'/'.$fileName;
    file_put_contents($path, $decoded);

    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    $post->title = request('title');
    $post->description = request('description');
    $post->category_id = request('category_id');
    $post->user_id = Auth::id();
    $post->photo = $fileName;
    $post->save();

    return response()->json([
        'post' => $post,
    ], 200);
}
```

In my vue template I used this in the html

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Image</label>
  <input type="file" @change="imageChanged" class="form-control">
</div>
```

The imageChanged method looks like this:

```
 imageChanged(e){
   var fileReader = new FileReader()
   fileReader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0])
   fileReader.onload = (e) => {
      this.post.photo = e.target.result
   }
 },
```

The edit post looks like this:

```
editPost(){
  axios.patch('/api/posts/' + this.update_post.id, {
      title: this.update_post.title,
      description: this.update_post.description,
      category_id: this.update_post.category_id,
      photo: this.update_post.photo
  })
  .then(response => {
    this.showPosts();
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

I see the following in my error log but have no idea what they mean:

```
#47 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#48 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#49 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#50 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#51 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\public\\index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#52 {main}
"}
```

How can I update the post with image?

Comment: did you check the error log ?

Comment: not familiar with that @rkj

Comment: check storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: shows me about 8000 lines of code.

Comment: if you look carefully that file, there you can see the cause of 500 error

Comment: I just updated my question with the errors I get. Also I tried to updated the values of the select tags and I also get  500 error. So it means like am not binding the data properly. Any solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173314/discussion-between-rkj-and-wosley-alarico).

Answer (score 0):

I then noticed that first I was using the wrong property name so I replaced my function using the $this.update_post, instead of this.post

```
imageChanged(e){
   var fileReader = new FileReader()
   fileReader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0])
   fileReader.onload = (e) => {
      this.post.photo = e.target.result
   }
 }
```

Then with @rkj tip I change the patch method and used put instead.